# What is the download size of Windows 10 Creators Update (version 1703)?

Tags: windows-10, windows-update, bandwidth, windows-10-v1703

How much Internet data will it take to download the Windows 10 Creators Update?

I do not care about the final size once the update is installed.  I need to know whether it is larger than 4GB, because then I have to buy some extra data before downloading it.  Note that I use the 64-bit version of Windows.

Comment: If you are low on bandwidth for the month you should wait until its pushed over Windows Update, as the update will be significantly smaller, then the ISO will be.  Additionally the (update) Media Creation Tool will provide you an estimate on the size of the download before it starts.  The ISO is going to be smaller then 4GB since, Windows 10 images are design to fit on standard sized DVDs, Microsoft doesn't have any (software) image larger then that at the moment.

Comment: I downloaded the full ISO image of each variety of version 1703 last night (both x86 and x64), and they were both under 4 GB.

Comment: Suggestion : Wait on downloading ISOs until you can get to a library or other free network connection.

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Did you have any lingering questions?

Comment: @Run5k Sorry to not reply, once it has installed (I will wait for the windows update version), I will know whether your answer is correct.  It was a useful answer, thus I have upvoted it.

Comment: I think it is related to your current Windows version. If you're using Windows Update Assistant, you can calculate the update size easily. First, download a part of the update using it (at least 1%), and notice the percent completed, I called this number n (e.g. if percentage is 1%, n equals 1). Cancel the update. Then, go to C:/Windows10Upgrade (C:/ is where your Windows is installed). You'll see a file with the format of ESD (Windows Electronic Software Download); enter its size on the calculator, and divide it to n, and multiply in 100. Now, the result will be the update size! ;)

Answer (score 6):

Here is a screen shot showing the full-sized ISO images for the Windows 10 Creators Update (version 1703), along with the x64 size highlighted for your reference:

[image: Windows 10 Version 1703 ISO Files]

Also, if you are concerned about the additional size involved with the inevitable cumulative update that will install once you are online, the current patch (15063.13) is relatively small at only 11 MB:

[image: KB4016251]

As a result, your data plan should have some breathing room to work with even if you decide to download the ISO image to install.  If you wait until you receive it automatically via Windows Update, it should be noticeably less than that.

Comment: I used the Windows Update Assistant going from v1607 to Creators Update earlier this week, and it downloaded approximately 3.5 GB .  There's more updates after the update, too.

Comment: I let it update _via Windows update_, it used up 3.89 GB from my first account (I have two internet accounts), at which point I ran out of data, but it failed to install.  Now it is appears to be starting from the **beginning** again with my second account of which there is isn't even 3GB left, so that will also fail.  It is doing this automatically as I type this (goodbye internet ...).  It also tried to automatically update at the end of last month, using up my last month's remaining data (which was more than 400MB).

Comment: Please keep in mind that we had this discussion *six months* ago.  A lot of things can change within the Windows world during that much time.  Honestly, it may have been prudent to download the 3.38 GB image file back in April when we originally addressed this question.  Then you could utilize a USB drive or DVD disc to upgrade to the baseline version of the Windows 10 Creators Update, and after that the only thing you would need to download is the latest Quality Update through Windows Update.  Once your data plan is restored, I would recommend doing that.

Answer (score 5):

I'm downloading it using the Upgrade Assistant.

I'm running 64-Bit English & it's downloading a 2.9GB ESD file.

[image: Refer screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

full-sized ISO images for the Windows 10 Creators Update (version 1703), along with the x64 size with international english it is about 4.0 GB.

Comment: First of all, welcome to Super User!  We always appreciate the contributions from our community members, but can you please provide us with a reference and/or screen shot to support your answer?  Our initial research has shown that the *"full-sized ISO images for the Windows 10 Creators Update (version 1703)"* are noticeably less than 4.0 GB.

Answer (score 0):

I should have taken some screenshots at the time, but after losing over 6 GB of space (I'm quite limited on it, right at the moment), I had to get rid of it to keep my SSD from being too full. I never like to go below 15 GB of free space. This update took me from 22.4 GB, to 14.2 GB on an X86 bit version of Windows.

Hopefully this info is useful to someone.

Comment: I think that because you were able to "get rid of it" you might just need to remove the rollback files after update to regain the disk space, see e.g. http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/regain-hard-disk-space-by-using-windows-update-cleanup-in-windows-7-and-8x/ **Make sure the update works stable first.**